# to dabble in vs to foray into

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I'd like to compare these two words in terms of meaning and usage.It seems like they mostly overlap to me but there are possible subtle differences.

I tried to give as many  example as to discern the difference. Do you think the meaning of the sentences would change if I swap the words each other in the following sentences.

To foray into means

> a short period of time being involved in an activity that is different
>   from and outside the range of a usual set of activities
>
> She made a brief foray into acting before becoming a teacher

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foray

> After a brief foray into politics, she returned to where she is most
>   comfortable - in the company of words.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foray

> Anna’s forays into cooking were never very successful.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/foray

---

To dabble in means

> to try something or take part in an activity in a way that is not
>   serious
>
> He first dabbled in politics when he was at law school.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dabble

> It's astounding that, at 24 years of age, the stand-up comic has
>   already dabbled in more professions than most people attempt in a
>   lifetime.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dabble

> When he was younger he dabbled in astrology.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dabble_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two words have quite different senses of purpose and intensity.

- The original (and still core) meanng of *dabble* is transitive: to get something wet by splashing or casual movement. You *dabble* your fingers in a fingerbowl to clean them. It implies little effort or seriousness. One who 'dabbles' in art is an amateur, not an artist.
- The original (and still core) meaning of *foray* is a "raid": a sudden, swift, violent attack to carry off plunder. To make a *foray* into politics is to swoop unexpectedly into an election, hoping to win because your opponents are surprised and disorganized, or at least to gain attention and publicity for your longer-term efforts.

  Note that *foray* is not ordinarily used as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Like you wrote, foray is to engage in an activity that is outside of one's given set of skills while dabble is more superficial, like dipping one's toes.

I dabbled in piano = i know how to push the keys but didnt go further.

After my foray into piano, i know how to reproduce a simple melody